# Where do Avandra and Melora reside?

Tags: dnd-4e, religions-and-deities

Reading through the descriptions of the different planes in the Manual of the Planes, I couldn't help but notice that these two goddesses were completely unmentioned. Kord, Moradin and Bahamut reside in Celestia, Pelor, Ioun and Erathis reside in Hestavar, and so on, but I could find no reference to Avandra or Melora.

Has there been any official word on where their "homes" are?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Rules Compendium, page 41, states

> Not all the gods live in astral dominions -...Avandra, Melora and Torog travel the world, and both Sehanine and Vecna wander the whole cosmos.

Answer (score 5):

I cannot find any with a brief look through relevant books for Avandra. Since Avandra is the Goddess of Travel, it could be she does not have a realm, preferring to roam the planes.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melora_%28Dungeons_&_Dragons%29), with no clear source:

> Like Avandra, Melora has no astral dominion, preferring to wander the cosmos.